# SwiftUI - How does Apple Music create their background gradient?

Tags: image, swiftui, apple-music

I was taking a look at the background that Apple Music uses when displaying the currently playing song, like these:

[image]
[image]

I really like the way that these backgrounds echo the color of the album cover, but I'm not entirely sure how I could implement something similar, given an Image. At first I thought it was just a magnified and blurred copy of the album Image, like this:

```
Image("album cover")
    .resizable()
    .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
    .blur(radius: 20)
```

But looking at the two images above I don't think this is the case, as not all colors in the cover image are included. Instead, do they use a radial gradient? If so, how do they pick which colors to use, and how could I do something similar, given an Image?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Python, but interesting related reading: [Python - Find dominant/most common color in an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3241929/python-find-dominant-most-common-color-in-an-image). Pick a color or three and you've got your gradient.

Comment: Also possibly related: [Get average color of UIImage in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26330924/get-average-color-of-uiimage-in-swift), [Getting main colors of a UIImage in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41552544/getting-main-colors-of-a-uiimage-in-swift), [Objective-c - Getting least used and most used color in a image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13694618/objective-c-getting-least-used-and-most-used-color-in-a-image), [Determine primary and secondary colors of a UIImage](/questions/15962893/determine-primary-and-secondary-colors-of-a-uiimage)

Comment: [Materials](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/material/)

Comment: Here is the [WWDC video](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc21/10021)

Answer (score 0):

I went through a similar exercise lately and here is what I've used

```
.background {
        ZStack {
            Rectangle()
                .fill(backgroundColor().gradient)
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)

            Rectangle()
                .fill(.ultraThinMaterial)
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        }
    }
```

Note that `.gradient` is available since iOS 16. The background color can be any swiftui color. In my case I'm using the [average color](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/musickit/artwork/backgroundcolor) of the song artwork available with MusicKit since iOS 15.

Comment: This could work with `ArtworkImage`, but not with `Image`, as in the question.

Comment: The code does not compile. You need to call `.fill(Color(cgColor: someArtwork.backgroundColor!).gradient)`.